# Can 0^0 be defined when it expresses a gradient?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

According to power rule, ${d\over dx}(x) = 1x^0$. So, on the line $y=x$, we have ${dy\over dx}=x^0$. The gradient at any point on this line is 1. However, substituting 0 for x into the derivative of the function gives $0^0$, which is undefined. Does this mean the gradient at the point where the line passes through the origin is undefined?

Comment: I would say $\frac{d}{dx}(x) = 1$.  Nothing else.  No need for the artificial $x^0$ in there.  See the many other posts here about $0^0$ for more.

Comment: $0^0$ is often defined as $1$ for a lot of reasons, like this. The key thing to know about that is the $x^y$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$